# Find string in specific cell in current row in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using exel 2016 and am starting my first vba script. I have a excel document with rows of different strings in each row in column B. I want to populate column D with with entries based on if conditions. Please see attached pictures
[image: Column B has entries filled, but I need to populate Column D]
[image: I need Column D and E filled based upon what text I find in Column B, example text below]

How can I write a vba macro to that will run against column D and E and read on each row the entry in Column B and then make a judgement on the write answer, I'm thinking something like this pseudocode:

```
Search for string in cell in Column B for current Row I'm on
If string contains "McDonald's"
then populate cell in column D for current Row as "Lunch" and in column E as "Visit". 
Move to next Row
Carry on with moving through Row's until you reach last Populated Row.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With a task like that I would first write the code for one row, then create a loop and test the loop with 2 or 3 rows, and then let the loop run for the entire sheet. Since you are new to VBA, you would have to learn how to read and write cell content in order to do the first row. Actually, that is very easy in VBA. I urge you to invest time in learning how to address cells. Many beginners don't, and they get stuck with terribly convoluted systems which, although they do work, in effect, prevent them from doing proper programming.

Comment: For a start: `If (Worksheets("SheetWhereDataIs").Cells(2,2).Value="McDonald's") then Worksheets("SheetWhereDataIs").Cells(2,4)="Lunch"`. As @Variatus said, you should include that code inside a loop. So search "excel vba find last row", and then "excel vba loop". Also consider gathering all conditions in an Array or in a helper sheet, in order to avoid hard-coding them.

Comment: Thank you for that. It proved really valuable. One part I'm struggling with in your example is how I can search for a string e.g. (in Cells(2,2) rather than finding an exact match as you did. Could you please help describe how I could change your code to search in each cell for a portion of a word?

Comment: You can try [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx), or [Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx). I would go with `InStr`.